# RecycleView Select multiples

Tags: android

How I can select multiples rows in a recycleview correctly ?

I see this example : https://github.com/kiddBubu/RecyclerViewDemo but is so bat because when move up or down screen value disappear or change  or assing position to other row, so bad.

I try show more content of the row.

Example :

```
Row 1 (uncollapsed)
Row 2 (uncollapsed) - > click - > (collapsed) add + padding or margin
Row 3 (uncollapsed)
.
.
Row x (uncollapsed)
```

But when I try move list up or down the value selected is randomly and others views change automatically, I don't know why, ListView, RecycleView  are equals...

I know how do with listviews normals with "tags" (but also is bad)

I don't want "expandablelistview".

Any help ?

**Update**

I want this efect : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuFFl.png

I have not found anything, not a complete example in google

Code :

I tried 4 or 5 methods, this is the first

```
boolean [] check; check = new Boolean[Fragment2.recyclerView.size()];



Arrays.fill(array, Boolean.FALSE);
```

.
.
.

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // l1
        public TextView text1,text2,text3,text4;
        LinearLayout imgLayout,l1;

        // l2
        public TextView text5,text6,text7;
        LinearLayout l2;
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            l1 = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.l1);
            imgLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgLayout);
            text1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            text3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
            text4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text4);

            l2 = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.l2);
            text5 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text5);
            text6 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text6);
            text7 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text7);

            int itemPosition = Fragment2.recyclerView.getChildPosition(itemView);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!check[itemPosition]) {
                        l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        l1.setEnabled(true);
                        check[itemPosition] = true;

                        l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        l2.setEnabled(false);

                    } else {
                        l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        l1.setEnabled(false);
                        check[itemPosition] = false;

                        l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        l2.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I try all examples from google and not work :(  I see this example, but nos is fully https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView#layout_viewholder2-xml

Comment: Check this link: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/. They guide you through an example of what you are looking for

Comment: Can you post any example full ? bacause I don't have the class " Crime "

Comment: Look what you are going to have to do is create an array to store selected items. Each time you click an item it is added to the selected array and in the onBindViewHolder just check which items have been selected and do something with them.

Comment: I tried save in a booleans[position]==true or false, but "The position" not work properly

Comment: Then add more code, can't feed you everything. Add code and we can see whats wrong

Comment: I updated, I can't find any solution, I go to make popup :(

Comment: I've solved with a popup, :( any form with listview ?

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView connects a data structure like an ArrayList via Adapter. Upon an update of the ArrayList, your RecyclerView's View objects should change state.

If I were to update multiple rows in a RecyclerView, I'd update the value inside the ArrayList and call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). So when I scroll, the element has been updated properly.

Comment: can you put any example ?

Comment: any example full to know how I do ?

Comment: He is not asking to add a list. He wants a dynamic list multiple clicks.
Go up / down, and do not miss the reference. He gave an example of github.